# How to assign value onClick from different component to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What i want to do :

- When i click my button i.e `Search` in `Navbar.js` i want to assign the search text in the variable `urlQuery` so i can pass it as props in `Episodes.js` component
- End goal is to pass the urlQuery from `Navbar.js` somehow to `Episodes.js` component so i can query the REST api

How do i achieve the desired behaviour pls help

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Episodes from './components/Episodes/Episodes'
import CustomNavbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Pagination from './components/Pagination/Pagination'
function App() {

  const [postsPerPage] = useState(20);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const url=`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode?page=${currentPage}`
  let urlQuery = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode?name=${SEARCH TEXT HERE}`

  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomNavbar />
      <Episodes
      urlQuery={urlQuery}
      url={url}
      />
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={36}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';

const customNavbar = () => {

  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Rick And Morty</Navbar.Brand>
      <Form inline>
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        <Button>Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
export default customNavbar
```

**Edit**

On Zohaib's suggestion this error is thrown

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js
  Line 14:48:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're passing the data through the URL? Would communicating directly from the child component to the parent component work for your use case?

Comment: Can you please ask that in Layman's terms ? didnt understand the question

Comment: If the URL does not change, is that okay?

Comment: No it has to change ...

Comment: Oops I misread the question. I meant the URL of the browser, but that's irrelevant. Give me a minute, I'll attempt to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Episodes from './components/Episodes/Episodes'
import CustomNavbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Pagination from './components/Pagination/Pagination'
function App() {

  const [postsPerPage] = useState(20);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [userSearchValue, setUserSearchValue] = useState('');

  const [url, setUrl] = useState(``);
  const [urlQuery, setUrlQuery] = useState(``)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode?page=${currentPage}`)
  }, [currentPage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUrlQuery(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode?name=${userSearchValue}`)
  }, [userSearchValue])

  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  const handleButtonClick = (searchValue) => {
      setUserSearchValue(searchValue);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomNavbar
      onButtonClick={handleButtonClick}
      />
      <Episodes
      urlQuery={urlQuery}
      url={url}
      />
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={36}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';

const customNavbar = ({ onButtonClick }) => {

    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Rick And Morty</Navbar.Brand>
      <Form inline>
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" value={searchValue} onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} />
        <Button onClick={() => onButtonClick(searchValue)}>Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
export default customNavbar
```

The important part here is you're passing down the `handleButtonClick` function to the child component (Navbar). This way you can call that parent function in the child component whenever you want (ie. when the user clicks the submit button).

Comment: this error `React Hook "useState" is called in function "customNavbar" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

Comment: nvm fixed it by Capitolizing `CustomNavbar`

Comment: Also `e is not defined error` and making it event also throws an error

Comment: Made a typo (updated the post) - try changing the line to this:

`<FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" value={searchValue} onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-einstein-54i78)?

Comment: Link only answers don't deserve upvotes. What if the page goes down? What if the page changes? Please pull the relevant code from the external page and add an explanation.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @3limin4t0r this question not deserves to remain long, So the answer is!

Answer (score 1):

There is a React guide about this specific problem: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Normally what you do is you manage the state in the parent. In this case `App` where you manage the search text state. You pass down a function to components to change this state. The components that depend upon this state are passed the value through the properties.

Here is an example:

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

function App() {
  const episodesURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode";
  
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = useState({});
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = new URL(episodesURL);
    url.searchParams.set("page", page);
    if (searchText) url.searchParams.set("name", searchText);
    
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      if (response.error) {
        setPageInfo({});
        setEpisodes([]);
      } else {
        setPageInfo(response.info);
        setEpisodes(response.results);
      }
    });
  }, [page, searchText]);

  const search = searchText => {
    setSearchText(searchText);
    setPage(1);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomNavbar search={search} />
      <Episodes episodes={episodes} />
      <Pagination setPage={setPage} info={pageInfo} />
    </div>
  );
}

function CustomNavbar({search}) {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  
  const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    search(searchText);
  };
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="search"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={event => setSearchText(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function Episodes({episodes}) {  
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>episode</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>air date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {episodes.map(episode => (
          <tr key={episode.id}>
            <td>{episode.episode}</td>
            <td>{episode.name}</td>
            <td>{episode.air_date}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function Pagination({setPage, info}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {info.prev && <a onClick={() => setPage(page => page - 1)}>previous</a>}
      {info.next && <a onClick={() => setPage(page => page + 1)}>next</a>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
th { text-align: left; }
a { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change urlQuery to state variable. Then, pass setUrlQuery to NavBar as a prop and on search button clickEvent call setUrlQuery function.

Comment: `<Button onClick={props.setUrlQuery(event.target.value)}>Search</Button>` Like this ? If yes its throwing an error

Comment: onClick={()=>props.setUrlQuery(event.target.value)} Check this or show me error

Comment: actually the error is with event. Try to pass hard coded value first.

Comment: check this link to get the value and pass it to function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194498/get-value-of-input-text-with-react-bootstrap

Comment: That was for class based components